# Front page isn't always chronological

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, sorting

I just edited [this post](https://superuser.com/a/378471/22317) and reloaded the front page. It had already updated the topic (the one with 10 up votes) to include my modification (*55s ago Daniel Beck*), but its position was out of the usual, chronological order. I have never seen this behavior before: Either nothing was updated (i.e. no recent modification by me) or everything, including the position.

After another minute or so, the topic took its expected position at the top of the list.

---

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: The draft for this topic was on my system since yesterday, so *I just edited* isn't exactly true anymore. Still, doesn't matter...

Comment: I expect this to be a caching issue

Comment: As Sathya said. The front page is heavily cached, so I'd almost *expect* some inconsistencies.

Comment: [This is caching!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qR0Uke2XNI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to caching, you can't always expect the homepage to be *exactly* in order. It should be close, and should refresh over some time -- if it does not (if the problem persists) let us know.

Comment: Sure, was just wondering since some parts apparently refresh more quickly.